# Spring mvc + JSF on GAE

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, model-view-controller, jsf

I have a problem with implementing spring mvc + primeFaces on GAE, i think that all works fine except when i try to modify values of my bean by sending post, values remain the same as before. Here is code:

**web.xml**

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/main-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>

     <context-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableThreading</param-name>

      <param-value>false</param-value>

        </context-param>



    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>



<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>



     <listener>
    <listener-class>
      com.remote.control.web.ApiKeyInitializer
    </listener-class>
  </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  



 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>




  <servlet> 
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>services</param-name>
   <param-value/>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**main-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

     <beans>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.remote.control.controller" />
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.remote.control.service" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/WEB-INF/res/"  />  



    <bean
        id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >

        <property
            name="prefix"
            value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />

        <property
            name="suffix"
            value=".xhtml" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config >

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>

    </application>




</faces-config>
```

**HomeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

      private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

      @Autowired
      Bean bean;


    @RequestMapping(value="/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView homeGet() {
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("index");  
        bean.setParam1("111111111");
        bean.setParam2("22222222222");
        bean.setParam3("3333333333");
        mv.addObject("task",bean);      
        return mv;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/home", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView homePost() {
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("index");

            logger.warning("param1"+ bean.getParam1());
            logger.warning("param2" + bean.getParam2());
            logger.warning("param3" + bean.getParam3());

            mv.addObject("task",bean);

    }


}
```

**Bean.java**

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Bean implements Serializable {


    private String param1;
    private String param2;
    private String param3;
    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }
    public void setParam1(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }
    public String getParam2() {
        return param2;
    }
    public void setParam2(String param2) {
        this.param2 = param2;
    }
    public String getParam3() {
        return param3;
    }
    public void setParam3(String param3) {
        this.param3 = param3;
    }



}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<html>

<ui:composition template="baseLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">

                <form action="home" method="post">
                <h:panelGrid style="margin-top:20px;" columns="2" cellpadding="10">

                    <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">

                        <p:inputText value="#{task.param1}" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{task.param2}" />


                        <p:inputTextarea value="#{task.param3}" id="text" rows="10" cols="50" />

                    </p:outputPanel>




                </h:panelGrid>
                <button value="submit" />

            </form>


    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>


</html>
```

Comment: try `h:form` and `h:commandButton`  instead of `<form` and `<button`

Comment: cant use h:form because it doesnt have action parameter and it doesnt send post to correct url

Comment: why aren't you using `action` attribute to specify bean method in your bean to deal with the submitted values ?

Answer (score 0):

Just turn

```
<form action="home" method="post">
    <h:panelGrid style="margin-top:20px;" columns="2" cellpadding="10">
        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">

            <p:inputText value="#{task.param1}" />
            <p:inputText value="#{task.param2}" />

            <p:inputTextarea value="#{task.param3}" id="text" rows="10" cols="50" />

        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <button value="submit" />

</form>
```

Into

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid style="margin-top:20px;" columns="2" cellpadding="10">
        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">

            <p:inputText value="#{task.param1}" />
            <p:inputText value="#{task.param2}" />

            <p:inputTextarea value="#{task.param3}" id="text" rows="10" cols="50" />

        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{task.myMethod}"/>

</h:form>
```

with the following method

```
public void myMethod(){
    System.out.println(param1);
    System.out.println(param2);
    System.out.println(param3);
}
```

Comment: Still it doesnt work good,ive changed it as you suggested, it displays good values in web browser, but in controller in post handle ive still old values, and they dont change unless i send next post. ive also made a method:                            public void submitHandler2(ActionEvent  e) {
  param1="kkakakakakakakaka2"; 
  } but it still works only after second post. I really dont know whats going here ;P